# Understanding Nested Structures

Tags: c++, visual-c++, struct, nested

I'm currently working on a program that requires a nested structure. Though, I am not sure I understand it. I'd like your help with this if anyone could. First week learning C++ so don't give me a hard time :P

I'm supposed create a Person structure containing two string members, first and last. Create an Address structure containing four string members, street, city, state, and zipcode. And also create a nested structure, Employee, that consists of three members. A Person member 
named name, an Address member named homeAddress and an int member named eid.

I think I've done most of it correctly, but I am getting an incomplete type is not allowed under my Address homeAddress for some reason. Also, when it says create a nested structure "Employee" does that mean I have to declare Employee somewhere?

Here is what I have so far, thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Person {
    string first;
    string last;
};

struct Address {
    string street;
    string city;
    string state;
    string zipcode;

    Person name;
    Address homeAddress;
    int eid;
};
```

Comment: So, where and how do "nested functions" come into the picture? The code you've shown doesn't have any functions, nested or otherwise.

Comment: Oops, typing error, I meant structures.

Comment: Where in your code does the word `Employee` appear? Where do you think it should appear? You know enough to define `struct Person` and `struct Address` - surely a `struct Employee` shouldn't pose any problems.

Comment: That is what I'm wondering about, when it says create a nested structure Employee, does that mean make a Person Employee; ?

Comment: The word "nested" doesn't make any sense in the context of the original problem, I must admit. As far as I can tell, it asks to define three structures, where the third contains fields whose types are the other two. Nothing particularly special about that, nor does this pattern (such as it is) have any special name, to my knowledge. "Nested class" usually means something different - class that's defined inside another class, as in `class Outer { class Inner {}; };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code was almost complete. It should be:

```
struct Person {
  string first;
  string last;
};

struct Address {
  string street;
  string city;
  string state;
  string zipcode;
};

struct Employee {
  Person name;
  Address homeAddress;
  int eid;
};
```

Now the misnomer here is that nested can also imply visibility or scope. Hence, if you wanted to define the structure `Address` and `Person` within `Employee`, it would look like this:

```
struct Employee {
  struct Address {
    //..
  };
  struct Employee {
    //..
  };
  Person name;
  Address homeAddress;
  int eid;
};
```

That way, you make the scope of `Person` and `Address` native to that of `Employee` alone.

Comment: Thank you. It makes more sense now.

Comment: @MatthewTingle: You're very welcome! Happy that I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are very close

```
struct Person {
    string first;
    string last;
};

struct Address {
    string street;
    string city;
    string state;
    string zipcode;
};

struct Employee {
    Person name;           // instance of Person struct from above
    Address homeAddress;   // instance of Address struct from above
    int eid;
};
```

Note that this last `struct` is "nested" as you describe it, since it is a `struct` that contains members that are two other types of `struct`.

Comment: Ah, so by nested, it just means nesting the other structures within the Employee structure, with Person name; and Address homeAddress; ?